# Creating a new Dataframe in R (including mean, sd) without using with()function

Tags: r

For programming class I need to create a new dataframe, including columns for mean and sd. This is what we got as potential solution:

```
newData<- with(showerData, aggregate(showerTime, by = list("Fach" = discipline), FUN= mean))
newData$deviation<- with(showerData, aggregate(showerTime, by = list(discipline), FUN= sd)) [,2]
newData$upper<- newData$x + newData$deviation                    
newData$lower<- newData$x - newData$deviation
newData <-set_names(newData, c("discipline","mean","sd","upper","lower"))
```

This works perfectly fine of course, but is there another way instead of using the with()function? Honestly I'm not very familiar with it and so I would definitely not use this in an exam. So... do you know another function for solving this?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want

```
newData<- data.frame(discipline=aggregate(showerData$showerTime, by = list("Fach" = discipline), FUN= mean))
newData$deviation<- aggregate(showerData$showerTime, by = list(discipline), FUN= sd) [,2]
newData$upper<- newData$x + newData$deviation                    
newData$lower<- newData$x - newData$deviation
newData <-set_names(newData, c("discipline","mean","sd","upper","lower"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know from where you get `newData$x` in the dataframe after `aggregate` but the equivalent of your commands using `dplyr` could be :

```
library(dplyr)

showerData %>%
  group_by(discipline) %>%
  summarise(showerTime = mean(showerTime), 
            deviation = sd(showerTime)) %>%
  mutate(upper = x + deviation, 
        lower = x - deviation) %>%
  rename_all(~c("discipline","mean","sd","upper","lower"))
```